# Pokemon Go causes overheating?

Tags: overheating, pokemon-go

I was curious about Pokemon Go so I downloaded it and started creating a character.  After about 3 minutes my phone said it was stopping all applications because my phone was overheating.  Curious as to how pokemon go could overheat my Galaxy S4?  As an aside, apps on my SD card keep moving back to device storage.  I had to put them back on SD card again to get Pokemon Go to download so that may have been related but I am not sure?

How can a phone overheat?

And yes, I have uninstalled Pokemon Go now.

Comment: How can a phone overheat?  By running Pokemon GO, which requires network connectivity, keeps the screen on the entire time, processor intensive, and getting your GPS location....

Comment: Mobile network and GPS will NOT overheat the phone by itself, if it does the device is defective or just poorly engineered... High screen brightness (esp with high pixel density) + High CPU usage + GPS + Mobile data... all these combined in their own right create heat, add the high current draw off the battery even more heat is generated. As many people with higher--end phones are learning with Pokemon Go it is a resource monster, using everything the phone has and those huge batteries, high current displays, etc. to their maximum potential, which also brings out the heat buildup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the game uses your mobile network and GPS constantly. which will over heat the phone. putting the app on sd would make no difference

Comment: I gifured it was that but how do people play it (or anything like that) for so long?  (I don't want people to think I am interested only in Pokemon Go ;-))

Comment: I doubt that it is because of the constant GPS and radio usage. More likely because of heavy CPU usage possible caused by rendering the AR.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is right. It adopts augmented reality technique and also makes use of your camera as well. It can takes up a lot of energy of your battery. So you may avoid running Pokemon Go together with any other apps.

Comment: AR can be disabled, which helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The default location settings for most phones are set to `High accuracy`, which uses GPS, Wi-fi and mobile networks to determine your location. Setting it to `Battery saving` or `Device only` would certainly help reduce the overheating inside the phone.

Comment: "Device only" uses GPS exclusively. If GPS is a factor in overheating, that setting will not improve matters. Battery saving is a better suggestion.

Comment: I have seen that.  It asks me if I want to use Wifi too (or maybe my previous phone did).  I didn't understand how WiFi could help in global positioning?